# How to say any Integer or Float along with custom parameter

Tags: mockito, any

I have method with following signature

```
public List<VwCmsListCaseStatus> fetchOpenCase(Long partyId, Long partyEventTypeId, Integer page, Integer pageLength, List<ColumnSortInfo> columnSortInfo);
```

I am trying to do when().thenReturn() but not sure how to say return me object nomatter parameter value are. I tried eq(Long.class) as well as anyLong() but none is working. So definitely I am missing something here.

Comment: According to doc https://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html when(openCaseDao.fetchOpenCase(anyLong(), anyLong(), anyInteger(), anyInteger(), ... ).thenReturn(vwOpenCaseList); shoukld work but not sure how to set last parameter as doc says "If you are using argument matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers. "

Comment: And your code is? And your definition of "not working" is?

Comment: Can you provide example which says return me object but i am sending any parameter with related type?

Comment: That's not how it works here. You provide the non working code, you clearly explain what you expect it to do and what it does instead, and we help you fixing it. We won't do your homework.

Comment: http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/92027-java-test-mockito.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to the following example

```
import org.mockito.Matchers.*;

@Test
public void testSomething() {
    Mockito.when(userRepository.getPassword(anyString())).thenReturn("PasswordMock");
    userService.validateCredential(username);
    Mockito.verify(userRepository).getPassword(username);
}
```

Comment: What if getPassword(String str, List<MyDto> mList)?

Comment: You can use anyList() for more information take a look this link https://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html